# Fluid Bootstrap Container Not Aligning Rows Vertically with align-items-* when used with height:100%

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a basic bootstrap container that has a fluid width. I want to be able to align three rows inside a sidebar to sit at the top, middle and bottom (much like [this demo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment) in the bootstrap documentation, but as a sidebar instead of full-width).

From what I can tell from other posts I've read this works with a fixed height, but not a fluid one (i.e. height 100%) - I need the sidebar and the content to both be the full height of the page. Then vertically align within that. However this doesn't seem to be possible. I was wondering if anyone knew a work around for this using bootstrap - it seem like it's something so commonly seen on the web these days that surely there must be a way of achieving it?

I've not added any custom CSS - all I'm attempting this with a classes available in Bootstrap (but I'm happy to create custom classes if required)

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        
        <div id="content" class="col-8 h-100">
            <p>Some Content</p>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar" class="col-4 h-100">

            <div id="logo" class="row align-items-start">
                <div class="col text-center">
                <p>Test Top</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="helpful-info" class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col text-center">
                <p>Test Middle</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="side-footer" class="row align-items-end">
                <div class="col text-center">
                <p>Test Bottom</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’ll need some custom classes for the sidebar section to keep it in place. Beyond that, you just need to setup the sidebar as `d-flex flex-column justify-content-between` and the divisions should spread out the full height. The sidebar height is set by calculating the viewport height minus the height of the navbar.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */
        padding: 48px 0 0; /* Height of navbar */
        box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .sidebar-sticky {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        padding-top: 0.5rem;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    }

    @supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {
        .sidebar-sticky {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
        }
    }

</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-0" href="#">Site name</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
        <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <main class="col-8 mr-auto" style="height: 200vh;">
            <h2>Content Area</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
                        
        </main>

        <nav class="col-4 d-block bg-light sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                <div id="logo" class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h6>Top Section</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="helpful-info" class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h6>Middle Section</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="side-footer" class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h6>Bottom Section</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```